# Show User Information in Block from View

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I have a block that shows some data from the User area (People) in Drupal 7. I have a rewrite setup that shows "VACANT" if there is no user selected for the content type. When logged in, I see users for 3 of the 4 contents I have created, which is correct. When logged out, I see VACANT for all of the contents.

Is there some restrictions on showing User data to the public? How can I make a certain Role visible to everyone?

EDIT::: Thanks to @Clive: **View user profiles [x] for anonymous**.

Comment: There's a 'view user profiles' permission (or something very similar), is that enabled for anonymous users?

Comment: I'll check that here... just got the "Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception" error I am dealing with now :|

Comment: @Clive make that an answer and I'll give you some points!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/admin/people/permissions` and tick the "View user profiles" permission for anonymous users:

[image]